# PInvoke managed heap corruption

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using this function to look up a keystroke from a low-level keyboard hook...

```vb
Const UnicodeBufferExSize As Integer = 64
Public Declare Function ToUnicodeEx Lib "user32" (wVirtKey As UInteger,
    wScanCode As UInteger,
    lpKeyState As Byte(),
    <Out()>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst:=UnicodeBufferExSize)> '<-- Note this line (#A)
    ByVal lpChar As System.Text.StringBuilder,
    cchBuff As Integer,
    wFlags As UInteger,
    dwhkl As IntPtr) As Integer

...

Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder(UnicodeBufferExSize) '<-- And this one (#B)

ToUnicodeEx(CUInt(lParam.vkCode),
            CUInt(lParam.scanCode),
            KeyState,
            SB,
            SB.Capacity, '<-- And this (#C)
            0,
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Handle)

GC.Collect()
Return SB.ToString()
```

The call to [ToUnicodeEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.tounicodeex) takes a parameter which indicates the size of the `StringBuilder` buffer to be populated (Line #C).

If I create a `StringBuilder` with no capacity argument (Line #B, current implementation seems to default to a capacity of 16 from reflection) and omit the `SizeConst` (Line #A), then the call *usually* succeeds but sometimes causes a Managed Heap Corruption Exception.

Now, I've added the `UnicodeBufferExSize` constant in the hope with will resolve the issue and it *seems* to have done so - but I don't know if it's really fixed it or just made it more rare.

Can someone please explain why simply passing in the buffer size isn't sufficient? And also confirm if my solution is correct or if there are any subtle bugs?

*(Note that the call to `GC.Collect()` triggers the problem more rapidly and is being used to aid debugging only.)*

Further to the (first) comment by Hans...

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Glue.exe
  Application Version:  3.1.3.0
  Application Timestamp:    52001dc3
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec4aa8e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000000532d0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 355b
  Additional Information 2: 355bc389704a5d6b4e279d0f0bd3355a
  Additional Information 3: 02ad
  Additional Information 4: 02ad05628a0a65c888b4805dfd9c6b58
```

Comment: You are asking us to guess what your old code looks like.  And quote a "Managed Heap Corruption Exception", that's not a real exception.  Screwing up the GC heap with bad declarations (do omit SizeConst), an uninitialized StringBuilder or a bad cchBuff will certainly cause trouble.  It eventually dies on a ExecutionEngineException.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I thought I was being explicit - Remove the `SizeConst` parameter from the line marked #A and the capacity value from line marked #B and you've got my old code which throws the exception. As to the exception detail being lacking, I agree - but I don't get one of the usual exception dialogues, I get a new window outside VS pop up telling me there was heap corruption and offering to let me attach a new debugger (after detaching the old). If I do so, I go straight into disassembly. If you can point me at how to get a more useful exception, I'd be grateful. I can add a scrnsht?

Comment: It is still unclear what you passed for cchBuf.  But clearly you were doing it wrong before and now you are doing it right. So I trust you fixed the problem. Do ignore my comment about removing SizeConst, it is required for this particular api since it doesn't return a zero-terminated string

Comment: I've always passed SB.Capacity to cchBuf. Would you mind explaining how you know it's required for this particular api?  Does the way I'm doing it now seem correct to you? (Sorry that's open-ended. Really, it should be "Where can I learn more about this?")